# CMD/Batch get active internet connection name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know how to get interface name

```
netsh interface show interface
```

[image: interface names]

I also know how to get wifi's names

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

[image: wlan profiles]

If I'm connected to Wi-Fi 2 adapter then I will be connected to one of the wlan profiles.

How can I can get same profile name to lan connection? It should be "TP-Link 2.4 2" according to my network connection settings. But if I try

```
netsh lan show profiles
```

All I get is "The Wired AutoConfig Service (dot3svc) is not running."

Ultimate goal is to print active connection name, so if ethernet 2 is active then TP-Link 2.4 2, if wi-fi is active then for example TP-Link_2064

[image: lan name]

[image: network connections]

EDIT: I activated wired autoconfig in services.msc. Now

```
netsh lan show profiles
```

gives me this
[image: lan profile]
but still there is no name of ethernet. I wonder where it gets into windows 10, because I surely didn't type name of ethernet.

Comment: So you just want to see which connection is active? So if you are currently connected to the `TP-Link_2064` you want to see only that?

Comment: I want to get active connection name either ethernet2 (TP-Link 2.4 2) or Wifi (TP-Link_2064), so I can use it in variable

Comment: But that works only for wifi, doesn't it? If I'm connected on wifi, your command works nicely, but it show nothing when on ethernet cable

Comment: Are you able to start the `wired AutoConfig service`

Comment: Yes, I started it just now. It shows some information, but the name is not there

Comment: Do you have multiple active connections? `wmic nic` has the information you need, but if you're running VMware (or probably other VM applications), you'll have extra connections that you aren't looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single active connection at any one time, this should provide you with the information you need?

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```py
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Name=" & Set "NetConnectionID="
For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe NIC Where ^
 "Not NetConnectionStatus Is Null And NetEnabled='TRUE'" ^
 Get Name^,NetConnectionID /Value 2^> NUL') Do Set "%%G" 2> NUL 1>&2
If Not Defined Name GoTo :EOF
Echo You are currently connected to Interface "%NetConnectionID%" on "%Name%"
Pause
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly that don't answer the question. If I run the command when connecter on ethernet it gives me this: You are currently connected to Interface "Ethernet 2" on "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM", when on wifi: You are currently connected to Interface "Wi-Fi 2" on "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 #2"
But I would like to get name of the wifi or ethernet connection

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by the name of the WiFi or Ethernet Connection then @kokosnakokos. If you are connected to WiFi, you could additionally get the broadcasted SSID, if it is, in fact, being broadcasted, but I'm not sure what other names a wired network would have. If I knew what you meant, I'm fairly sure that a modification of the above could be made.